# Can "zero" be used to describe uncountable nouns?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

> “There was **zero courage** in this verdict,” he said. ”I think this goes to the jury not wanting to make a difficult decision."

I learned that mass nouns cannot be enumerated.

Yes, I know that **zero courage** can be replaced with **no courage**, but, since **zero** is a number, I wonder whether *zero courage* is ungrammatical or only sloppy style.

Comment: You should know that the sentence above is fairly poor use of English, although done rather commonly. **Zero courage** is a dull attempt at [hyperbole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole) (see some answers below). Far worse, though, is **this goes to** to mean **this happened because**. In clear English, you would just say "The jurors chose this verdict only because they were afraid to make a difficult decision." But the dull English quoted in the question is very realistic and commonplace.

Answer (score 12):

One [definition of zero](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zero) is

> **2** the absence of a measurable quantity

However, this is a noun. [As an adjective](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/zero_2), zero means

> not any or no

Based on this definition, it is correct to use it to describe a mass noun to say there is none of it.

I've noticed that using "zero" instead of "no" is usually used to emphasize the lack of whatever it's describing.

Answer (score 4):

OED definitions include...

> Nought or nothing **reckoned as a number** denoted by the figure 0
>   That is of the amount expressed by zero, i.e. none at all;
>   in Math. also transf. applied to a value of a function corresponding to the value 0 of the variable(s).
>   *Hence (**colloq.**) more widely as adj. in the sense ‘**no, not any**’.*
>   [emphasis mine].

That's to say, by traditional definitions and usage, OP is correct in saying that *zero* is a *number* - so it shouldn't be used as a [quantifier](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Quantifier.htm), in contexts where you wouldn't use any other number. But in fact it's commonly used that way colloquially (usually only in *spoken* informal contexts).

---

Having said that, there are restrictions on its use...

> ?It's zero good hoping people will accept this as a reasonable utterance, even in casual speech.

Actually, I suppose it's possible *some* native speakers (certainly not me! :) *will* accept that contrived example. But I'm betting the vast majority wouldn't, so my advice to learners would be to avoid the form completely and always use **no** instead. You'll never be wrong that way.

Comment: This native speaker agrees with your assessment of **zero good**.

Comment: @Ben: Would you also accept that [*"This topic holds **zero interest** for me"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22holds+zero+interest%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (with a few written instances in Google Books there) is either "acceptable", or at least "not as unacceptable" as my *"It's zero good"* (which has zero instances)? I know some learners will think *"Ah! This looks subtle and interesting. I'd really like to master this aspect of idiomatic use!"*. But I stand by my final paragraph - too much effort, too little benefit, and too much risk of *still* getting it wrong.

Comment: Yes, **zero interest** also sounds acceptable to me, as the same informal, emphatic kind of phrasing as **zero courage**. And yes to your second point, too: while I think that making mistakes and getting corrected is an important part of learning, not to be prevented, wrestling with the subtleties of when **zero** can and cannot replace **no** does not seem like a fruitful use of a learner's time. This sort of thing requires an ear for the language, which comes from experience, not from rules people can memorize.

Comment: @Ben: Exactly. But based on answers+votes here, a casual visitor to this question would probably be left with the impression OP's cited usage is "normal, acceptable". Whereas so far as I'm concerned it's well beyond the pale in all but the most casual/colloquial speech, and even then I'd be inclined to suspect the linguistic competence of the speaker.

Comment: Indeed the current votes suggest that this is a matter of ordinary grammar, which is wrong. I hope that whatever answer gets selected (if that ever happens) indicates clearly that **zero courage** is a variation from normal usage, and explains what a speaker is trying to do by making that variation: namely, "punch up" the ordinary phrase a bit (in a rather hackneyed way).

Comment: @Ben: Well, I've upvoted your answer mainly because of "rhetorical flourish". I think it *is* valid to say the usage is "ungrammatical". As evidence, I'd cite the fact that there are no written instances of "showed zero courage" or "gave zero benefit" in Google Books - but there are thousands of the former, and *tens* of thousands of the latter using ***no*** instead of ***zero***. Some deviations from "valid" grammar are acceptable in casual speech in certain circumstances, but the general principle here for learners should simply be "avoid this usage, or risk seeming illiterate".

Comment: Happily, your comments here have indeed given me some ideas to improve my answer, plus I added a comment on the question itself. Do you have any thoughts about explaining to EFL learners how to understand and learn from real usage—in this case, second-rate usage? (That seems to be what the OP is actually trying to do.)

Comment: @Ben: Unless I'm much mistaken, you and I agree that there are *some* contexts (involving *certain* words, in *certain* real-world situations) where at least *some* speakers wouldn't object to using "zero" as a quantifier for a non-countable, abstract quality. But acceptability varies from person to person, so the only useful advice remains "don't do it".

Comment: I don't think either of us thinks that frequency counts of a phrase are conclusive evidence of grammaticality, since phrases are grammatical the first time they're used, but here's a bit more [evidence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22zero+enthusiasm%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: Yes, I think we basically agree. If we have a difference, it's a matter of emphasis. It's probably best that both our answers are up, and I'll try to improve mine based on what I've learned from this conversation. I especially like your example of **zero good** to illustrate clear-cut ungrammaticality, yet only a fluent speaker can see why that's so much worse.

Answer (score 4):

It's a rhetorical flourish.

The person who said **zero courage** is ["bending the rules"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6985/what-does-bend-the-rule-mean/26046#26046) of ordinary usage. To a native speaker, saying **zero** as a synonym for **no** is a reasonable variation from normal usage. The ordinary phrasing is **no courage**; that would have drawn no attention to itself. Saying **zero courage** is emphatic: it's like saying "There was not even a little bit of courage in this verdict. There was no courage *at all.*"

While **zero courage** in this context doesn't sound ungrammatical or sloppy to most native speakers, there are very similar phrases that no native speaker would say because they break rather than bend ordinary usage. For example, nobody would say **two courage**. That would be incomprehensible. See FumbleFingers' answer for another good example of going too far.

You shouldn't take the example as evidence contradicting the principle that mass nouns cannot be enumerated. It's evidence that **zero** can sometimes be stretched into an intensified version of **no**.

There is no precise general rule for when you can and can't do this kind of thing. You just have to get a sense of how far you can bend the language without breaking it. That can only come with (long) experience.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible meanings of *zero* is "the lowest possible amount or level; nothing at all"; one of the example phrases shown by the OALD is "zero inflation."
The example is similar to yours, since both *courage* and *inflation* are uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

Some nouns like "courage" are quantifiable but not really measurable; one could describe Fred as having "more" courage than Joe, but there's no standard unit of courage that would make it possible to say that e.g. Fred has 2.7 more couragions than Joe.

The lack of defined units, however, doesn't affect "zero" because *zero doesn't require units*.  If something is has a length of zero inches, zero centimeters, and zero angstroms, or zero miles, it has zero length; the units don't matter.  If something has a mass of zero ounces, zero milligrams, or zero tons, it has zero mass; again, the units don't matter.  That principle can be extended to things like "courage": it's not possible to specify any particular non-zero quantity of courage because that would require defining units, but since "zero" doesn't require units, it is possible to have zero courage.