# Can you call me after sometime?

Tags: politeness

I want to know which question is correct and polite with an interviewer:

> Would you please call me after sometimes?

Or

> Can you please call me after somtime?

Comment: Forget the word ***after***. Come to that, there's no obvious reason to include ***sometime*** either.

Comment: Options: Would/Could you please call me (back) (a little) later (today, this afternoon, this evening)? Would it suit you to...would it be possible for you to ....?) May I call you back ....?  All are polite and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

**Sometimes** means that a certain thing or event happens occasionally, probably irregularly, as opposed to always or consistently, and as opposed to never or rarely.

> **Sometimes** the grocery store has mangoes for less than a dollar.

> **Sometimes** you have to break the rules.

The point of the second example is to deny that you must always follow rules. There are occasions, which are not predictable and do not follow any simple pattern, when it is wiser to break or [bend](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26046/6700) a rule that should be followed most of the time.

---

**Sometime** is an adverb that means "at some unspecified time in the future".

> Why don't you come up and see me sometime? —Mae West (details [here](https://wordhistories.net/2019/07/20/come-see-me-sometime/); this is a very famous line)

This line is an invitation to visit Mae West in her bedroom—not right now, maybe not today, maybe months from now—at some opportune time in the future, whenever that may occur.

---

You are thinking of the phrase **some time**. This is two words, not one.

**Some time** is a noun that means an unspecified time, either a specific moment in time or a duration of time. When you say **after some time**, the meaning is unambiguous: "after an unspecified amount of time" (i.e. an unspecified duration). Usually **some time** in this second sense means a fairly long time, or a long enough amount of time to matter.

> It will take me **some time** to fix your car. (This means, "I can't fix your car quickly.")

> I've got **some time** to kill. (This means, "I have nothing scheduled to do right now, and there is enough time before my next commitment that you and I could do something fun together.")

> Many students who cram for exams get a passing grade, but **after some time**, they retain almost nothing of the subject matter. (Modified from this [source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Who_s_Got_the_Right_Time/-_aomhMLEZAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22after%20some%20time%22&pg=PA43&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22after%20some%20time%22). This means that the students don't forget the subject matter immediately after the exam; perhaps two weeks or more pass before the students forget the subject matter.)

> The 13th Battalion of The King's Regiment was made up almost entirely of Lancashire men, mostly from Liverpool and Manchester. It had been formed in Scotland, trained in England, and, **after some time** on coastal defence it was sent out to India for garrison duty at Secunderabad. ([Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Return_Via_Rangoon/PCbAAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22after+some+time%22&pg=PT27&printsec=frontcover). This means that the 13th Battalion spent perhaps a month or two on coastal defense—long enough to be significant.)

---

But the best phrase for your request is: **at your convenience**:

> Please call me **at your convenience**.

This is the polite, formal way to request, in business, that someone call you soon. It means that your need for the call is not urgent, but it is important. It implies that the other party should wait for a convenient moment to call, but should not delay unnecessarily.

If you ask someone to call you **after some time**, you are requesting that they *not* call you back immediately. "Please call me **after some time**" requests that the other party *delay* a significant amount of time before calling you. This is probably not what you want to ask.